# Prefix equivalents in English?

Tags: equivalent-phrase

Are there any equivalent or similar prefixes or nicknames for 阿 or 小 (added in front of a name in Chinese) in English?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Chinese language.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a universal prefix equivalent to 小 or 阿. Certainly you can add 'Little', but that's not a prefix, but an adjective.

In the West, nicknames follow different patterns, mainly using the first syllable of the full name and adding an `[i]` (*-ie*, *-y* or similar):

E.g. John --> Johnnie, Andrew ---> Andy, Lisa ---> Lizzy, etc.

Other countries have similar fashions, adding *-(e)tte* [French], *-chen*, *-le* [German, with some regional differences], *-ito*,*-ita* [Spanish] *-ka*, *-ška*, *-čka*, *-ek*, (Czech and other Slavic with different spellings).

Some nicknames are completely different from the formal given name, e.g. Richard --> Dick.